# $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$ and that $g$ is uniformly continuous on $g([a,b])$. Then $f\circ g$ is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, uniform-continuity

Suppose that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$ and that $g$ is uniformly continuous on $g([a,b])$ . Then $f\circ g$ is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$.

Could anyone give me a hint for answering this question?

Comment: Have you tried applying the definition?

Comment: I feel that there is a problem in the question ... the g([a,b]) @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: Yes, $g[a,b]$ should be $f[a,b]$ and you have to show that $g\circ f$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: If you want $f\circ g$ to be uniformly continuous, then it is $g$ which should be defined (and uniformly continuous) on $[a, b]$, and $f$ which should be uniformly continuous on $g([a, b])$. If $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[a, b]$ and $g$ is uniformly continuous on $f([a, b])$, then it is $g\circ f$ which is uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider that you can make $|f(x)-f(y)|$ as small as you wish by choosing $|x-y|$ small enough.

Consider that you can $|g(f(x))-g(f(y))|$ as small as you wish by choosing $|f(x)-f(y)|$ small enough.

Now, given $\epsilon$, how can you pick a $\delta$ small enough, to ensure that
$$|x-y|< \delta \implies |g(f(x))-g(f(y))| <\epsilon \quad \text{for any $x,y \in [a,b]$} $$

---

Let $\epsilon$ be given. Since $g$ is uniformely continuous on $f([a,b])$, I can find some $\delta_1$ such that 
$$|f(x)-f(y)| < \delta_1 \implies |g(f(x))-g(f(y))| <\epsilon$$.

If only I could find some $\delta_2$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)| < \delta_1$...

Now read the first sentence of this post.

Comment: Could you suggest hints?

Comment: Added some comments.